# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index' using RASA

Tags: python, python-3.x, rasa-core

i try to use RASA to build a sample bot, but i got ths error message,

```
Bot loaded. Type a message and press enter (use '/stop' to exit):
sad
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\channels\channel.py", line 291, in on_message_wrapper
    on_new_message(message)
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\agent.py", line 316, in handle_message
    return processor.handle_message(message)
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\processor.py", line 86, in handle_message
    self._predict_and_execute_next_action(message, tracker)
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\processor.py", line 305, in _predict_and_execute_next_action
    action, policy, confidence = self.predict_next_action(tracker)
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\processor.py", line 168, in predict_next_action
    probabilities, policy = self._get_next_action_probabilities(tracker)
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\processor.py", line 478, in _get_next_action_probabilities
    tracker, self.domain)
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\policies\ensemble.py", line 288, in probabilities_using_best_policy
    if (result.index(max_confidence) ==
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'
```

i use :

```
PYTHON  3.6.0
RASA CORE   0.12.0
RASA NLU    0.13.0
TENSORFLOW  1.10.0
PROTOBUF    3.6.0
```

ho it possible to solve this ?
Thank you

Comment: This usually means you have tried to treat an object of `NoneType` as a `dict` or similar. Are you able to show enough of your code for us to see what is causing the error please? A minimal, complete, verifiable example will help us to give a useful answer.

Comment: i try to follow this tutoriel https://rasa.com/docs/core/quickstart/?_ga=2.72956439.547278926.1542012600-930128378.1541579964

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With rasa_core version `0.12` you have to provide a [policy configuration](https://rasa.com/docs/core/policies/#id1) for the training. You can e.g. a default template for that from [Github](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/blob/master/default_config.yml).
E.g. save the following snippet in a file called `default_config.yml`:

```
policies:
  - name: KerasPolicy
    epochs: 100
    max_history: 5
  - name: FallbackPolicy
    fallback_action_name: 'action_default_fallback'
  - name: MemoizationPolicy
    max_history: 5
  - name: FormPolicy
```

Then train Rasa Core with:

```
python -m rasa_core.train \
  -d <path to domain file> \
  -s <path to stories> \
  -c default_config.yml \
  -o models/dialogue
```

Then run the trained model with:

```
python -m rasa_core.run -d models/dialogue
```

Comment: is that a way to show chat on browser instead of shell view ? https://www.afnay.com/images/akelad.PNG

Comment: Sure. Checkout https://github.com/mrbot-ai/rasa-webchat and https://rasa.com/docs/core/connectors/#socketio-setup

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not trained the dialogue model or Policies have not been created properly. Try training your dialogue module again with following command

```
python -m rasa_core.train -d domain.yml -s stories.md -o models/dialogue
```

It will be good if you can you show contents following directory:

```
./models/dialogue
```

It should look something like below.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reponse, i have three folders, domain.json, domain.yml and policy_metadata.json https://www142.lunapic.com/do-not-link-here-use-hosting-instead/154221643710004182?3627821905

Comment: files* not folders, i can't edit my last comment, i don't knew why !